# Graph Declaration for Adjacency List

Tags: c++, graph

I am getting

> error:incompatible types when assigning to type 'struct listnode' from type 'struct listnode*'
>
> error: invalid type argument of '->' have('struct      listnode')

What am I doing wrong with the pointer here? Thanks in advance

```
     #include <stdio.h>
     #include <stdlib.h>

     struct listnode{
     int vertex;
    struct listnode *next;
     };
 struct Graph{
  int V;
  int E;
  struct listnode *adj;
 };


 void print(struct Graph *G);

  struct Graph* initategraph(){
    int i,source,dest;
    struct listnode *temp;
    struct Graph *G=(struct Graph*)malloc(sizeof(struct Graph));
    if(!G)
       {printf("Memory not available");
         return;
       }
    printf("Enter the vertex no. and edges \n");
    scanf("%d %d",&G->V,&G->E);
    G->adj = malloc(G->V*sizeof(struct listnode));
    for(i=0;i<G->V;i++)
    {
        G->adj[i] =(struct listnode *)malloc(sizeof(struct listnode));
        G->adj[i]->vertex = i;
        G->adj[i]->next=G->adj[i];
    }
    for(i=0;i<G->E;i++){
        scanf("%d %d",&source,&dest);

      temp= (struct listnode *)malloc(sizeof(struct listnode));
        temp->vertex=dest;
        temp->next=G->adj[source];
        G->adj[source]->next=temp;

        temp =(struct listnode *)malloc(sizeof(struct listnode));
        temp->vertex=source;
        temp->next=G->adj[dest];
        G->adj[dest]->next=temp;


      }
    return G;
 } 
  void print(struct Graph *G){
   int i;
   struct listnode *temp;
    for(i=0;i<G->V;i++){
    temp=G->adj[i];
    while(temp)
    {
        printf("%d --> ",temp->vertex);
        temp=temp->next;
     }
     printf("\n\n");
   }
 }

 void main()
   {
   struct Graph *G;
   G=initategraph();
   print(G);


   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all `G->adj = malloc(G->V*sizeof(struct listnode));` already allocates a dynamic memory with a siez of `G-V` elements of type `struct listnode`. So remove this semantically incorrect statement from the inside of your loop: `G->adj[i] =(struct listnode *)malloc(sizeof(struct listnode));`

The type of `G->adj[i]` is `struct listnode` not `struct listnode*`. Change `G->adj[i]->vertex` to `G->adj[i].vertex`.

The type of `G->adj[i].next` is `struct listnode*` and the type of `G->adj[i]`is `struct listnode`. Change `G->adj[i]->next=G->adj[i];` to `G->adj[i].next = &( G->adj[i] );`. `G->adj[i]` is the `i`th element itself and not a pointer to the `i`th element.

Note `&( G->adj[i] )` is similar to `G->adj + i`. `adj[i]` is similar to `*(adj + i)` and `&(adj[i])` is similar to `adj + i`.

Note after `G->adj[i].next = &( G->adj[i] );` the member `next` refers to its own `struct listnode`. I don`t know if that is what you want to do.

Adapt your code like this:

```
struct Graph* initategraph(){
    int i,source,dest;
    struct listnode *temp;
    struct Graph *G=(struct Graph*)malloc(sizeof(struct Graph));
    if( G =0 NULL )
    {
        printf("Memory not available");
        return NULL;
    }
    printf("Enter the vertex no. and edges \n");
    scanf("%d %d",&G->V,&G->E);
    G->adj = malloc(G->V*sizeof(struct listnode));
    for( i=0; i<G->V; i++ )
    {
        G->adj[i].vertex = i;
        G->adj[i].next = &( G->adj[i] );
    }
    for( i=0; i<G->E; i++ ){
        scanf("%d %d",&source,&dest);
        temp= (struct listnode *)malloc(sizeof(struct listnode));
        temp->vertex=dest;
        temp->next = &( G->adj[source] );
        G->adj[source].next = temp;

        temp =(struct listnode *)malloc(sizeof(struct listnode));
        temp->vertex=source;
        temp->next = &( G->adj[dest] );
        G->adj[dest].next = temp;
    }
    return G;
}
```

Note: I don't known if the algorithm is doing what you want it to do. I only fixed the compile errors.